# Marionnette layout not showing ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, handlebars.js

My layout isn't showing my item view.

Here is my markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">header div</div>
    <div id="main">main div</div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var EventView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile("Name of event: {{name}}"),
    model: new Backbone.Model({
        name: "Game"
    }),
});
var AppLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: '#wrapper',

    regions: {
        header: '#header',
        main: '#main'
    }

});
var layout = new AppLayout();
layout.render();
var event1 = new EventView();
layout.main.show(event1);
```

All I want is

```
<div id="main">Name of event: Game</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you first need to insert your layout inside an app region.

```
App = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();
App.addRegions({
    centerRegion: '#center'
});

var layout = new AppLayout();
App.centerRegion.show(layout);
var event1 = new EventView();
layout.main.show(event1);
```

Comment: Yes this was totally the problem. I didn't realize I had to append the Layout object to the DOM first.